# How to speed up my build

Tags: linux, compiling, performance, parallelism, priority

I am doing a build on a Linux machine with Ubuntu 10.04 on it. How can I really speed up my build? I have 4 CPUs and lots of RAM. I already reniced the process group to -20. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: No mention of what your doing or in what area you are looking for speed? There are more trade off decisions to be made than magic "go faster" settings.

Comment: I meant to reduce the build time by leveraging some Linux settings.

Comment: What are you building?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most software build processes use `make`. Make sure you make `make` use the `-j` argument with a number usually about twice the number of CPUs you have, so `make -j 8` would be appropriate for your case.

Comment: Double the number of cores? I always heard [number of cores plus one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025587/whats-best-value-for-make-j/3025596#3025596)

Comment: I think that depends on whether your jobs are large or small. +1 makes sense for big jobs, x2 for lots of little ones. My testing with building the kernel on my 3 core machine shows that x2 (`-j 6`) is just about the sweet spot. More actually goes a little faster but the machine becomes unacceptably unresponsive. I like to be able to still type while something is going on :)

Comment: Usually the "optimal" number of processes is between n+1 and 2n+1 depending on how much time is spent in I/O activity. The idea is to have some process ready to run each time one of the running processes needs to stop for some I/O (or ends). If you processes are CPU bound go for n+1. If you processes are I/O bound go for 2n or even 3n (if your disks are fast enough). In my experience, 2n is a good value to compile something.

Comment: Beware, this doesn't work with all possible make-based build systems. In particular, recursive builds where a top-level Makefile kicks off make(1) in subdirectories in a specific order will generally fail to build correctly when you let make(1) build in parallel unless you are very careful about documenting dependencies in the top-level Makefile. While it can be made to work, parallel builds are the best excuse I know to rethink your build system to avoid the need for recursive builds.

Comment: @Warren Young, yes we have also seen problems with parallel builds. We have a recursive build environment as you have described above.

Comment: Just as a little more help: You can also specify those argument in your environment with `MAKEFLAGS`. To better control the systems load I recommend using also the argument -l [load].  
I personal prefer the long versions `--jobs` and `--load-average` for readability.

Answer (score 11):

Reniceing the process group to -20 is a bad idea. This niceness level should be used only by the top-priority system-critical tasks. Otherwise you can loose responsiveness or even freeze the system. And the potential compilation-time benefit would be marginal.

Apart from [what Caleb already suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19419/how-to-speed-up-my-build/19420#19420), if you compile a lot, you can also speed up builds using [compiler cache](http://ccache.samba.org/) or distribute the build tasks across multiple computers across a network using [distcc](http://distcc.org/) or [icecream](http://old-en.opensuse.org/Icecream).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to rozcietrzewiacz's answer:

First big improvement would be the disks, use faster IOPs disks, i.e. something that runs at 10,000 or 15,000 rpm, ideally SSD and then you are only limited by your purse.

Random example, Samsung's 6Gbps SATA 2 SSD:

http://www.engadget.com/2011/08/17/samsungs-6gbps-ssd-gets-a-consumer-label-october-ship-date/

OCZ have some of the most extreme hardware, 500,000 IOPs:

http://www.engadget.com/2011/08/02/oczs-z-drive-r4-pcie-ssd-offers-2-800mb-sec-500-000-iops-pl/

You could try copying the tree to a `tmpfs` file system but Linux's file cache is already pretty good.

For rapid development usage the build would go faster if you disabled all the optimisations.  These tend to be '90s era tweaks when processors were slow, it's pretty much all about IO now.

The most convoluted approach I can imagine is using `cramfs` to store a large part of the tree that doesn't change.  Using a compressed file system would mean less disk accesses underneath.